# CMS page is not being saved with HTML tags : Magento 1.9.1.0

Tags: content-management-system, magento-1.9

I am using Magento 1.9.1.0.

When I try to update my CMS page and press `Save and Continue Edit` button, it redirects me to the CMS Pages list back (it should be stay on continue edit page). Also none of my content being saved.

If i try entering a plain text (without HTML Tags like ) it is being saved.

So it is not working with `HTML Tags`

Comment: are you using the wysiwyg editor?  I would recommend shutting that off in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was the onClick="" sections in  tags (sending google analytics events). I couldn't find any errors or open quotes in it but removing them made it start working again. We aren't using those on click events anymore so removing them was a quick solution for us.

Other people have mentioned that having HTML tags without closing tags can cause it to go back to the CMS list instead of saving too.